# How to handle this error caused by uploading a problematic JPEG?

Tags: php, error-handling, gd

I have a website where the public can upload JPEGs.

Someone from the public was uploading an invalid JPEG that was causing the site to crash for them.

PHP said...

> imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Premature end of JPEG file

I wasn't sure how to get around this, so I Googled and found [this site](http://worcesterwideweb.com/2008/03/17/php-5-and-imagecreatefromjpeg-recoverable-error-premature-end-of-jpeg-file/). It told me to add...

```
ini_set('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', 1);
```

I added that in my `index.php` (the bootstrap of my site, where I do other `ini_set()`).

This didn't seem to fix it.

How can I handle this case of invalid JPEGs? Am I doing something wrong with the INI set? I'm on a shared host so I can't change `php.ini` directly.

I'm using Kohana 2.3, and its [Image library](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/image), but I don't think it is really relevant here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try sticking an `@` character before the command:

```
$image = @imagecreatefromjpeg("file.jpg");
if(!$image) die("Sorry, bad JPEG");
```

It's dirty and probably obsolete (not to mention slow), but it'll probably make your code not fail.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the error suppressor operator! Thanks, I know its not recommended and ugly as hell, but it *may* be my only hope.

Comment: The `@` is only ugly if failures go completely unchecked and are allowed to propagate. Since you're checking for error conditions on the very next line, this is acceptable usage of `@`.

Comment: @deceze I'm glad the programming gods approve :D

Comment: @mattbasta where did you learn the `@` function. I learnt php by reading a book. it didn't have this. couldn't find anything searching `php @`, how do i find out such stuff?

Answer (score 5):

You would usually work with `imagecreatefromjpeg` like this:

```
$img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
if (!$img) {
    // handle error yourself
}
```

Note the `@` in front of `imagecreatefromjpeg`, which is used to suppress errors. Unfortunatly I can't tell you how Kohana does this internally and if it could be persuaded to do the same thing.

Comment: It does the same, just uses a variable function because it supports multiple drivers.